# Below is my class I want recordId from the Database.error

Tags: apex, class, record, database, get

```
   for (Database.SaveResult result : saveResultList) {    
        if (result.isSuccess()) { 
            successCount++;
            system.debug('Get id of success Record'+result.getid());
        } else {
            errorCount++;
            for (Database.Error err : result.getErrors()) {
                errorDetailList.add(new SerializableError(err));
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
public class SerializableError {
    private String statusCode;
    private String message;
    private List<String> fields;

    public SerializableError(Database.Error error) {
        this.statusCode = error.getStatusCode().name();
        this.message = error.getMessage();
        this.fields = error.getFields();   
    }

    public String getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public List<String> getFields() {
        return fields;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) and read [How to Answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/415142/edit) your question to add more details like what you are doing to get save result?

Comment: Assuming that saveResultList is the result of an update (because you have omitted that part of the code), the `getId()` method from `Database.SaveResult` should return the ID. So you could store `result.getId()` regardless of the success of the operation and store it according to your needs.

Answer (score 3):

- For the insert action it's not possible to get the record id while getting the error (record is not inserted to the database yet!).
- For the Database.update you can easily access record id by 'result.getid()' everywhere, inside the for loop.